# can we use modelform to update an existing instance of a model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i know that modelform in django is a form which is used to generate a model instance but suppose if we want to update an already present model instance through a modelform, then will it update a model or create a whole new instance.

Comment: Pass `instance=existing_instance` to the modelform?

Answer (score 11):

### The save() method

Every ModelForm also has a **save()** method. This method creates and saves a database object from the data bound to the form. A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance.

**If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of the specified model**:

```
>>> from myapp.models import Article
>>> from myapp.forms import ArticleForm

# Create a form instance from POST data.
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST)

# Save a new Article object from the form's data.
>>> new_article = f.save()

# Create a form to edit an existing Article, but use
# POST data to populate the form.
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
>>> f.save()
```

For the other hand, also you can specify if you want to create a new instance or not...

> Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False).
>   When you use a simple save() on a form, all data – including
>   many-to-many data – is saved without the need for any additional
>   method calls.

***Source***: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: does it mean that first of all i have to check whether the instance exist or not and then i will render form?

Comment: @Gagan Exactly, if you really want to update first of all you have to get the item you want and then `update` with the `save() method`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is explained in the [documentation on `ModelForm`s [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform):

> ```
> # Creating a form to change an existing article.
> >>> article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
> >>> form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
> ```

So we can create a form and pass an already existing instance, like:

```
MyModelForm(instance=my_modelinstance)
```

If you *render* that form, it will contain the values of the `instance` initally.

We can also use the form to update the model, like:

```
my_form = MyModelForm(request.POST, instance=my_modelinstance)
```

If we then perform a `my_form.save()`, the `my_modelinstance` will be updated with the data in the `request.POST`, and updated in the database.

Comment: when i re-render the form then , it does not populate its fields with current values

Comment: @Gagan: can you share the view that renders the form to edit?

Answer (score 3):

A subclass of ModelForm can accept an existing model instance as the keyword argument instance; if this is supplied, save() will update that instance. If it’s not supplied, save() will create a new instance of the specified model.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method